# Another version of list of string with a wrong output

Tags: c++

this code should transform a char* to my own struct SList, which is just a list of words from the former array (separated with spaces), then to create an ostream << operator for it

but here is the output:

```
fu 
fuc 
fuc 
fucy
```

what is wrong? It seems to access to the same place every time, but debugger showed that indexes work good.
Also string is forbidden to be used.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n = 16;
char * input = new char [16] {'n', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'a', 'y', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'u', 'c', 'y', '\0'};

struct Word{
    char * letters;
    int length;
};

struct SList {
    Word * wordList;
    int length;
};

int listSize(char * s, int n){
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(*(s + i) == ' ') result++;
    }
    return result + 1;
}

SList createList(char * s, int n){
    int _listSize = listSize(s, n);
    SList myList;
    myList.length = _listSize;
    myList.wordList = new Word [myList.length];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int counter = 0;
        char symbol = *(s + i);
        Word toAdd;
        while(symbol != ' '){
            symbol = *(s + i);
            if(i == n) break;
            counter++;
            i++;
        }
        toAdd.length = counter - 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < toAdd.length; j++){
            *(toAdd.letters + j) = *(s + i + j - (toAdd.length+1));
        }
        *(myList.wordList + k) = toAdd;
        k++;
        i--;
    }
    return myList;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, SList &myList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < myList.wordList[i].length; j++){
            os << myList.wordList[i].letters[j];
        }
        os << endl;
    }
    return os;
}


int main(){
SList myList = createList(input, n);
  cout << myList;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you post your [actual code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (I'm not seeing `SList` definition anywhere.)

Comment: Indeed, this code [does not compile](https://www.ideone.com/ywunpU).  The output you're showing must be from code you are not showing here.  Please [edit] your question to fix this oversight.

Comment: You are missing a main() function with an example of how you are trying to use this.

Comment: `*(toAdd.letters + j)` invokes *undefined behavior* - you haven't initialized the pointer `toAdd.letters`

Comment: @UnholySheep thank you, it worked, you saved my grade!

Answer (score -2):

I cannot compile/debug your example code as it is lacking the definition of `Word` and `SList`. But according to your debugging results, the detection of the word lengths is correct but not the content. So the problem needs to be somewhere in the logic of `*(s + i + j - (toAdd.length+1))`.

My advice would be to try [strncat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat) instead. It will keep you from counting character positions up and down.

Finally you should end up in something like:

```cpp
strncat(toAdd.letters, s + i - 1 - toAdd.length, toAdd.length);
```